# Is there any function in Java to retrieve the day of the year in three digits?

Tags: java

I want to rename my file name according to yyyy_[DayOfTheYear]. The day of the year should be in 3
digits always. For example, 01-01-2021 -> 2021_001 ; 31-01-2021 -> 2021_031 ; 31-12-2021 -> 2021_365
Is there any predefined method to get the 3 digits in Java?

Comment: There are two separate problems here - retrieving the day of year, and padding 0s to the left. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Sweeper padding 0s to the left is obviously like the last option. Getting the day is not difficult but my question was for getting the day in 3 digits by default without any padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`LocalDate::getDayOfYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfYear--).

The instance of `LocalDate` may be formatted using `String.format` or using [`DateTimeFormatter::ISO_ORDINAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ORDINAL_DATE).  The latter allows to get year and day of year, however, these values are delimited with `'-'`, which can be replaced if necessary.

Example:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
      
      DateTimeFormatter yearDayOfYear = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ORDINAL_DATE;

      System.out.printf("%s -> %4d_%03d%n", today, today.getYear(), today.getDayOfYear());
      System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", today, today.format(yearDayOfYear).replace('-', '_'));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2021-02-03 -> 2021_034
2021-02-03 -> 2021_034
```

Comment: It doesn't return 3 digits. For 01-01-2021 it returns 1, not 001.

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
        System.err.println(df.format(LocalDate.now().getDayOfYear()));

Comment: @ShivamThakur, provided an example with custom formatting.